# UsingCoaslesce function with distinct

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to fetch some data from a relational database and order it based on the payed_at column. In case payed_at is null, I want he updated_at column to be used instead. My query so far is bellow:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT "orders".*  
 FROM "orders" INNER JOIN "order_items" ON "order_items"."order_id" = "orders"."id"  
 WHERE (orders.state = 'payed') AND (physical = true) AND (kind = 'output')   
 ORDER BY coalesce(orders.payed_at, orders.updated_at) DESC
 LIMIT 200 OFFSET 0
```

I'm getting the following error from Postgres:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

It might be a problem with DISTINCT in the query, because when I remove DISTINCT word I get no error.

I'm using the coalesce function.

I'm stuck with this error.

Comment: That's a pretty clear error message, which part didn't you understand? Add your coalesced column to the select and then you can order by it.

Comment: I didn't understand. How would it be like in the given example ? @Levesque ?

Comment: Are you including `DISTINCT` because you have duplicates in your results?

Comment: That was the problem. How dumb I am... Thank you.

Comment: In fact the ORM puts distinct automatically.

Comment: I was only printing the query it has generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error states that when using `SELECT DISTINCT` and ordering by an expression, you must include the expression in the `SELECT` list.  Your expression is the `COALESCE`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT coalesce(orders.payed_at, orders.updated_at),...
FROM "orders"
INNER JOIN "order_items" ON "order_items"."order_id" = "orders"."id"
WHERE (orders.STATE = 'payed')
    AND (physical = true)
    AND (kind = 'output')
ORDER BY coalesce(orders.payed_at, orders.updated_at) DESC LIMIT 200 OFFSET 0
```